# I send twice the data when doing a registration in android with php

Tags: php, android

I'm new to Android with php, I try to register in android with php from server side, everything was fine, I inserted correctly but then I decided that I needed to send an email and when doing a test the data was sent twice, and I jumped The toast : The user already exists, the email if it arrives and shows me that message, I've been reviewing for a long time because I do not find the error, I leave the script in case I want to help, thank you.

PHP:

```
<?php
public function createUser($username, $pass, $email){
        if($this->isUserExist($username)){
            return 3;
        }else if($this->isEmailExist($email)){
            return 4;
        }else{
            //Para enviar el correo :
            //$dg=mail('santos97.rosario@gmail.com', '', 'Registro Exitoso','');
            //$password = md5($pass);
            $password = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT, array("cost"=>11));
            $stmt = $this->con->prepare("INSERT INTO usuarios (username, password, email,imagen,activate) VALUES (?, ?, ?, '','0');");
            $stmt->bind_param("sss",$username,$password,$email);

            if($stmt->execute()){
                return 1;
                //$stmt->closeCursor();
            }else{
                return 2; 
            }
        }
    }
?>
<?php 
require_once '../includes/DbOperations.php';
$response = array();

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
if(isset($_POST['username']) and 
        isset($_POST['password']) and 
            isset($_POST['email']))
    {
    //operate the data further 

    $db = new DbOperations(); 

    $result = $db->createUser($_POST['username'],$_POST['password'],$_POST['email']);

    if($result == 1){
        //
        $response['error'] = false; 
        $response['message'] = "Registered User Correctly";
        mail('dfdf@gmail.com', 'Prueba', 'Prueba','From : victorosario@gmail.com');
    }elseif($result == 2){
        $response['error'] = true; 
        $response['message'] = "An error occurred";         
    }elseif($result == 3){
        $response['error'] = true; 
        $response['message'] = "User already exists, please choose another";                        
    }elseif($result == 4){
        $response['error'] = true; 
        $response['message'] = "Email already exists, please choose another";
    }else{
        $response['error'] = true; 
        $response['message'] = "An error occurred";
    }
}else{
    $response['error'] = true; 
    $response['message'] = "Fill in the data";
}
}else{
$response['error'] = true; 
$response['message'] = "Answer Invalid";
}

echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

Y este es mi codigo android :

```
private void registerUser() {
    final String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
    final String username = editTextUsername.getText().toString().trim();
    final String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();

    progressDialog.setMessage("Registrando usuario...");
    progressDialog.show();

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            Constants.URL_REGISTER,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();

                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), jsonObject.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    progressDialog.hide();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("username", username);
            params.put("email", email);
            params.put("password", password);
            return params;
        }
    };


    RequestHandler.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);


}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view == buttonRegister)
        registerUser();
    if(view == textViewLogin)
        startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class));
}
```

Comment: use https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer to send email in php

Comment: I think you just read the title...

Comment: Add Create User Php code too